# RaisePropertyChanged in another class using expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression

Solved

I've been looking for a while and I can't find the solution. Maybe because I'm not so fluent with expressions.

What I want to do, is to raise a property change in Class2 from the Class1. I can do this when I communicate the string of the property to update. What I want is to use expressions to avoid typos.

The prototype below works perfectly well when I'm using strings to define the parameter to update in the class2.

I use the event aggregator to propagate the property to update.

I have a Class1 looking like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    private void RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(Expression<Func<Class2>> expression)
    {
        ServiceLocator.EventAggregator
                      .GetEvent<UpdateClass2Property>().Publish(expression);
    }
}
```

In the class2, I have:

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2 (IEventAggregator evt)
    {
        evt.GetEvent<UpdateClass2Property>()
           .Subscribe(x => RaisePropertyChanged(() => x));
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return SomeFunction(); }
    }
}
```

And the event:

```
internal class UpdateClass2Property :
    CompositePresentationEvent<Expression<Func<Class2>>> { }
```

When I use `RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(() => Name);`, I have an error at compilation time:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Class2'

---

EDIT: (solved)

I manage to solve the compilation error by doing this

```
private void RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(Expression<Func<Class2, string>> expression)
{
       ServiceLocator.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateClass2Property>().Publish(expression);
}
```

So now I can do this in my Class1

```
public string Property1
        {
            get { return _property1; }
            set { _property1 = value;
                RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(x => x.Class2Property);
            }
        }
```

But now I have to solve the problem in the Class2 to retrieve the property name.

I managed to solve this by doing this in my Class2:

```
public Class2(IEventAggregator evt)
        {
            evt.GetEvent<UpdateClass2Property>().Subscribe(Method);
        }

        private void Method(Expression<Func<Class2, string>> expression)
        {
            var memberExpr = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpr == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("propertyExpression should represent access to a member");
            string memberName = memberExpr.Member.Name;
            RaisePropertyChanged(memberName);
        }
```

Of course, I changed the signature of UpdateSnapshotProperty

```
internal class UpdateSnapshotProperty : CompositePresentationEvent<Expression<Func<SnapshotViewModel, string>>> { }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, not exactly an answer but have you considered switching to the [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)-Attribute, as demonstrated in this article: http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2012/10/29/2117/inotifypropertychanged-propertyname-past-present-and-hopes-for-the-future ? The expression stuff seem pretty cryptic...

Comment: I'm using .net 4.0 but thanks

Answer (score 1):

For property change you need to `pass on string but your expression is expecting instance of Class2`.

Change

```
private void RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(Expression<Func<Class2>> expression)
```

to

```
private void RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(Expression<Func<string>> expression)
```

Also

```
internal class UpdateClass2Property :
    CompositePresentationEvent<Expression<Func<Class2>>> { }
```

should be

```
internal class UpdateClass2Property :
    CompositePresentationEvent<Expression<Func<string>>> { }
```

Comment: Ok It works fine but it does not work if I rename "Name" into "Name1" in Class2 or Class1.

Comment: That's because expression `() => Name` will return value of `Name` property and not actual string `Name`.

Comment: It should be `RaiseClass2PropertyChanged(() => "Name")`

Comment: The purpose of this is not to use string directly so that I can do something like RaiseClass2PropertyChange( x => x.Class2Property)

Comment: But you don't have class2 instance with class1. So, how will you get to know the property name in class1?

Comment: I have edited the question. Indeed, I don't class2 instance but I can know what property the class has.

Comment: Ok, now i get it what you meant but anyhow you got it solved so nevermind. :)